# When a record is created, how to ensure a method is run before a setter_method is initialized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 form I have a find_or_create field with an attached setter method, and I have a method that I'm currently running before_validate. I need the before_validate method to run before the setter method. How should I modify my code to achieve this?

My form contains:

```
<%= f.select(:country_id, Country.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank:true) %>
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :state_id, Country.order(:name), :states, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
<%= f.text_field :new_state_name, placeholder: "..or enter a new state" %>
<%= f.input :city_name %>
```

In the model I have

```
def city_name
 city.try(:name)
end

def city_name=(name)
  if name.present?
    set_city = City.find_or_initialize_by_name_and_state_id(name, self.state_id)
    if set_city.new_record?
      set_city.state_id = state_id
      set_city.save(:validate => false )
      self.city = set_city
    else
      self.city = set_city
    end
  end
end

before_validation :create_new_state

def create_new_state
  if new_state_name.present? && country_id.present?
    new_state = State.create( name: new_state_name, country_id: country_id )
    self.state = new_state.id
  end
end
```

The idea is that a user can select a Country and a State, then type in a City name that is found against the name and the state. If no such City exists it is created.

In addition, if the required State does not exist in the select field, the user can instead type in a new state in the new_state_name field. On save, the new state is created, and should be associated with the new city (if a new state is entered, the city must be new).

The problem I have is that the city_name setter appears to run before the `before_validation` method. So the new city is created with whatever value is selected in the state select (including if is blank?).

What is a better way to structure my code to achieve the desired result? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it. (Hope you don't mind me changing your model code around a bit.)

```
delegate :name, to: :city, prefix: true
delegate :name, to: :state, prefix: true

attr_writer :city_name, :state_name
attr_accessible :city_name, :state_name

before_validate :find_or_create_city_and_state

validates :city, :state, presence: true

private

def find_or_create_city_and_state
  if state_name
    state = State.find_or_create_by_name_and_country_id(state_name, country.id)
    self.state = state

    if city_name # Nested since this doesn't make any sense without a state, presumably
      city = City.find_or_create_by_name_and_state_id(city_name, state.id)
      self.city = city
    end
  end
end
```

In your form, call the fields `city_name` and `state_name` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi veraricus, thanks this is a useful start. I do want to keep state as a select field + new state text field. It makes more sense in my use case. Any idea how I could achieve this?